# i was adding font to my flutter app by it does not work correctly

Tags: flutter, fonts

i was tring to change font in my flutter app. i downloaded my font in a folder called fonts and extracted it from google fonts then add it in pubspec.yaml file then i wrote that code in my main.dart

my main.dart

```
     Text(
            'My lovely app',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 25.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontFamily: 'Pacifico',
            ),
          ),
```

my pubspec.yaml file

```
assets:
  - assets/profile.jpg
```

what should i do ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you didn't add any font from what you linked us from your pubspec.yaml

Following the [official documentation on how to use a custom font](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/fonts), you need to add the font file (.ttf or .otf) in your asset folder then import it through your pubspec.yaml as such:

```
  fonts:
    - family: Raleway
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Raleway-Regular.ttf
        - asset: fonts/Raleway-Italic.ttf
          style: italic
```

Don't forget to restart the app with `flutter run` to see changes